# IOS pkpass download multiple passes at once

Tags: ios, passbook, pkpass

So I've managed to have single `pkpass` working with download button. However I am looking for solution that let's you download multiple passes at once for example for multiple legs tickets.

there is that: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/distributing_and_updating_a_pass

which says:

> Provide a bundle of passes to enable your user to download multiple passes at once. To create the pass bundle:
> Create a .zip file containing the .pkpass files for the passes that are part of the bundle.
> Change the extension of the .zip file to .pkpasses.
> You can distribute a bundle of passes the same way you distribute a single pass. The MIME type for a bundle of passes is "application/vnd.apple.pkpasses".

But I did that and it's seen as a generic file download, and not opening with passbook. Is there a a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out, it will be available for IOS 15. so it's a future feature.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10092/